# How to add totals up and display them in a text box

Tags: javascript, menu

When trying to get my total to pop up, I can't seem to get it. Above this code in my .js file is the toggle check boxes; all of it works as of right now, but adding them together and coming up with a total in the `txtTotal` box is the only thing I'm struggling with.

```
  var total;
  var outputArea;
  var btnCompute;
  function ToggleBurgers() {
var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkBurgers');
var burgers = document.getElementById('divBurgers');

if (checkbox.checked) {
    burgers.style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
    burgers.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
}
 function ToggleFries(){
 var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkFries');
 var fries = document.getElementById('divFries');

if (checkbox.checked) {
    fries.style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
    fries.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
}

function ToggleDrinks(){
var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkDrinks')
var drinks = document.getElementById('divDrinks');

if (checkbox.checked) {
    drinks.style.visibility = 'visible';
   }else {
     drinks.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } 
}


  function ComputeTotal() {
     var total = 0;
     var burgers = document.getElementById('divBurgers');
     var fries = document.getElementById('divFries');
     var drinks = document.getElementById('divDrinks');
     var radBurgerRegular = document.getElementById('radBurgerRegular');
     var radBurgerCheese = document.getElementById('radBurgerCheese');
     var radBurgerBacon = document.getElementById('radBurgerBacon');
     var radBurgerBaconCheese = document.getElementById('radBurgerBaconCheese');
     var radFriesSmall = document.getElementById('radFriesSmall');
     var radFriesMedium = document.getElementById('radFriesMedium');
     var radFriesLarge = document.getElementById('radFriesLarge');
     var radDrinkSoda = document.getElementById('radDrinkSoda');
     var radDrinkWater = document.getElementById('radDrinkWater');
     var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
     outputArea.innerHTML = total + divBurgers + divFries + divDrinks;

  if (burgers.checked){
  if (radBurgerRegular.checked){ 
    total = total + radBurgerRegular;
  }if (radBurgerCheese.checked){
    total = total + radBurgerCheese;
  }if (radBurgerBacon.checked){
    total = total + radBurgerBacon;
  }if (radBurgerBaconCheese.checked){
    total = total + radBurgerBaconCheese;
  }
  }else if (fries.checked){
    if (radFriesSmall.checked){
        total = total + radFriesSmall;
    }if (radFriesMedium.checked){
        total = total + radFriesMedium;
    }if (radFriesSmall.checked){
        total = total + radFriesLarge;
    }
    } else if (drinks.checked){
    if (radDrinkSoda.checked){
        total = total + radDrinkSoda;
    }if (radDrinkWater.checked){
        total = total + radDrinkWater;
       }
   }


 }


function init() {
   var chkBurgers = document.getElementById('chkBurgers');
   chkBurgers.onchange = ToggleBurgers;

   var chkFries = document.getElementById('chkFries');
   chkFries.onchange = ToggleFries;

   var chkDrinks = document.getElementById('chkDrinks');
   chkDrinks.onchange = ToggleDrinks;

   var btnCompute = document.getElementById('btnCompute');
   btnCompute.onclick = ComputeTotal;

   var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
   outputArea.innerHTML = total
}

window.onload = init;
```

HTML code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Restaurant Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div class="topbar">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <!--Burgers CheckBox-->
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkBurgers" id="chkBurgers" />     <label for="chkBurgers">Burgers</label>
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Burger Menu-->
        <div class="cell" id="divBurgers" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerRegular" /><label for="radBurgerRegular">Regular (4.19)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerCheese" /><label for="radBurgerCheese">w/ Cheese (4.79)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerBacon" /><label for="radBurgerBacon">w/ Bacon (4.79)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerBaconCheese" /><label for="radBurgerBaconCheese">w/ Bacon and Cheese (5.39)</label><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">

        <!--Fries CheckBox-->
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkFries" id="chkFries" /><label for="chkFries">Fries</label>
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Fries Menu-->
        <div class="cell" id="divFries" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <input type="radio" name="radFries" id="radFriesSmall" /><label for="radFriesSmall">Small (2.39)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radFries" id="radFriesMedium" /><label for="radFriesMedium">Medium (3.09)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radFries" id="radFriesLarge" /><label for="radFriesSmall">Large (4.99)</label><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">

        <!--Drinks CheckBox-->
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkDrinks" id="chkDrinks" /><label  for="chkDrinks">Drinks</label>
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Drink Menu-->
        <div class="cell" id="divDrinks" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <input type="radio" name="radDrinks" id="radDrinkSoda" /><label   for="radDrinkSoda">Soda (1.69)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radDrinks" id="radDrinkWater" /><label for="radDrinkWater">Bottled Water (1.49)</label><br />
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Compute Button and Total Field-->
        <div class="cell" style="float:right;">
            Total Meal Cost: <input type="text" name="txtTotal" id="txtTotal" /><br /><br />
            <button id="btnCompute" name="btnCompute">Compute Total</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Chapter9.css">
<script src="Chapter9.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "you can't seem to get it"? is the value incorrect? I see a few potential bugs but need more info. also please add the HTML code

Comment: would it be helpful to add both the full HTML and .js code?

Comment: yes please. not enough info yet

Comment: do i add it in the comment? such as this?

Comment: click edit under your post

Comment: there we go i finally got it, sorry if its a Newbish question, im really struggling ive had to learn javascript in 5 days and it is extremely hard.

Comment: okay so what are you trying to do on this line: `outputArea.innerHTML = total + divBurgers + divFries + divDrinks;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, you want to get rid of the `else`'s in the block where you are checking if things are checked. that only allows you to get Burger or Fries or Drink, when you want to be able to get one of each.

so that should be:

```
if(burgers.checked){
    if(radBurgerRegular.checked){
        total = total + radBurgerRegular;
    }
    ...
}
if(fries.checked){
    ...
}
if(drinks.checked){
    ...
}
```

Additionally, you are doing all of this adding to total, and then not doing anything with it.

Move this:

```
 var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
 outputArea.innerHTML = total + divBurgers + divFries + divDrinks;
```

to the bottom of the function (and get rid of all the divBurgers, divFries stuff):

```
 var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
 outputArea.innerHTML = total;
```

The next problem is that nowhere is the price actually being added. When you `getElementById()`, that value does not magically become the price that is in parenthesis. You need to replace `total = total + radBurgerRegular` with the price:

```
if(burgers.checked){
    if(radBurgerRegular.checked){
        total = total + 4.19;
    }
    ...
}
```

lastly, you want to change the display area to a span instead of an input. change:

```
Total Meal Cost: <input type="text" name="txtTotal" id="txtTotal" />
```

to:

```
Total Meal Cost: <span id="txtTotal"></span>
```

and that should do it!

EDIT:

last thing, you need to change the following lines:

```
 var burgers = document.getElementById('divBurgers');
 var fries = document.getElementById('divFries');
 var drinks = document.getElementById('divDrinks');
```

to this:

```
 var burgers = document.getElementById('chkBurgers');
 var fries = document.getElementById('chkFries');
 var drinks = document.getElementById('chkDrinks');
```

because a div cannot be "checked" and will always return undefined (false).

Comment: i have replaced what you have told me to when i click the items to add together and hit total it doesn't display my total still.

Comment: and changing the input to span it says total undefined.

Comment: what does the actual error say when you click the button? copy paste

Comment: there is no error in the console, i am running it on chrome, and i edit it using Notepad++

Comment: where does it say something is undefined?

Comment: Total Meal Cost: undefined when you load the HTML page and dont click compute total, once you hit Compute total it goes to 0 and when you click on any options and hit compute total nothing happens

Comment: ah. okay. delete the two lines:

  `var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');`
 `outputArea.innerHTML = total`

from the bottom of init(). that should get rid of the undefined

Comment: now where getting somewhere, now it just says 0 when you select items to add to the total

Comment: okay, did you replace all of the radBurgerRegular type things with the actual price in the ifs?

Comment: Yes everything has a price, I want to thing it has something to do with the 'var total = 0; ?

Comment: as long as that is at the top of `ComputeTotal` then its fine. Did you move the  `var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');`
 `outputArea.innerHTML = total;` to the bottom of `ComputeTotal()`?

Comment: yes its at the bottom, that code then } meaning end of the function.

Comment: okay get rid of `var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal'); outputArea.innerHTML = total;` lines from bottom of `init()`. and put a `console.log(total);` at the bottom of `ComputeTotal`. When you refresh the page, there should be nothing next to `Total Meal Cost:`. Open the console, click compute a couple times and tell me what you see.

Comment: no problem, also just another bug i saw: in the "fries" section of the if's, you have small fries instead of large fries. so anytime you check small fries, it adds the cost twice, and large fries it doesn't ever add

Comment: got it changed, you made my life so much more easier! i had to learn javascript in 4-5 days its so confusing.

Comment: haha no problem. one easy way to help you debug your own code is to use `console.log()`. Put it anywhere where things aren't working like you expect. If the console, matches what you think it should be, that piece is probably okay and the bug is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Total is undefined in init.

Replace

```
 var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
   outputArea.innerHTML = total
```

with

```
var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
   outputArea.innerHTML = 0;
```

Or possibly a better option is to initialize total.

```
total = 0;    
var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
       outputArea.innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: and it is declared but never initialized

Comment: still not the problem

Comment: check your console. if you're throwing an error on init, it will block the rest of your code.

Comment: outputArea.innerHTML = total + divBurgers + divFries + divDrinks; i thought that would display the items added together.

Comment: i replaced the code with what you said, my console does't report any errors but my total isn't added or displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the function ComputeTotal. 
I propose you to take a look to the following implementation:

```js
    var total;
    var outputArea;
    var btnCompute;
    function ToggleBurgers() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkBurgers');
        var burgers = document.getElementById('divBurgers');

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            burgers.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
            burgers.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    function ToggleFries(){
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkFries');
        var fries = document.getElementById('divFries');

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            fries.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
            fries.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    function ToggleDrinks(){
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('chkDrinks')
        var drinks = document.getElementById('divDrinks');

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            drinks.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }else {
            drinks.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }


    function ComputeTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        var burgersCost = 0;
        var friesCost = 0;
        var drinksCost = 0;

        if (document.getElementById('chkBurgers').checked) {
            var burgersObj = document.querySelector('input[name="radBurgers"]:checked');
            var burgersValFromLabel = document.querySelector('label[for="' + burgersObj.id + '"]').textContent;
            burgersCost = burgersValFromLabel.substring(burgersValFromLabel.lastIndexOf("(")+1,burgersValFromLabel.lastIndexOf(")"));
        }

        if (document.getElementById('chkFries').checked) {
            var friesObj = document.querySelector('input[name="radFries"]:checked');
            var friesValFromLabel = document.querySelector('label[for="' + friesObj.id + '"]').textContent;
            friesCost = friesValFromLabel.substring(friesValFromLabel.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, friesValFromLabel.lastIndexOf(")"));
        }

        if (document.getElementById('chkDrinks').checked) {
            var drinksObj = document.querySelector('input[name="radDrinks"]:checked');
            var drinksValFromLabel = document.querySelector('label[for="' + drinksObj.id + '"]').textContent;
            drinksCost = drinksValFromLabel.substring(drinksValFromLabel.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, drinksValFromLabel.lastIndexOf(")"));
        }


        var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
        outputArea.value = total + parseFloat(burgersCost) + parseFloat(friesCost) + parseFloat(drinksCost);
    }


    function init() {
        var chkBurgers = document.getElementById('chkBurgers');
        chkBurgers.onchange = ToggleBurgers;

        var chkFries = document.getElementById('chkFries');
        chkFries.onchange = ToggleFries;

        var chkDrinks = document.getElementById('chkDrinks');
        chkDrinks.onchange = ToggleDrinks;

        var btnCompute = document.getElementById('btnCompute');
        btnCompute.onclick = ComputeTotal;

        var outputArea = document.getElementById('txtTotal');
        outputArea.innerHTML = total
    }

    window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="topbar">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <!--Burgers CheckBox-->
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkBurgers" id="chkBurgers" />     <label for="chkBurgers">Burgers</label>
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Burger Menu-->
        <div class="cell" id="divBurgers" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerRegular" /><label for="radBurgerRegular">Regular (4.19)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerCheese" /><label for="radBurgerCheese">w/ Cheese (4.79)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerBacon" /><label for="radBurgerBacon">w/ Bacon (4.79)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radBurgers" id="radBurgerBaconCheese" /><label for="radBurgerBaconCheese">w/ Bacon and Cheese (5.39)</label><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">

        <!--Fries CheckBox-->
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkFries" id="chkFries" /><label for="chkFries">Fries</label>
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Fries Menu-->
        <div class="cell" id="divFries" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <input type="radio" name="radFries" id="radFriesSmall" /><label for="radFriesSmall">Small (2.39)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radFries" id="radFriesMedium" /><label for="radFriesMedium">Medium (3.09)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radFries" id="radFriesLarge" /><label for="radFriesSmall">Large (4.99)</label><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">

        <!--Drinks CheckBox-->
        <div class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkDrinks" id="chkDrinks" /><label  for="chkDrinks">Drinks</label>
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Drink Menu-->
        <div class="cell" id="divDrinks" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <input type="radio" name="radDrinks" id="radDrinkSoda" /><label   for="radDrinkSoda">Soda (1.69)</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="radDrinks" id="radDrinkWater" /><label for="radDrinkWater">Bottled Water (1.49)</label><br />
        </div>

        <!--Cell Containing Compute Button and Total Field-->
        <div class="cell" style="float:right;">
            Total Meal Cost: <input type="text" name="txtTotal" id="txtTotal" /><br /><br />
            <button id="btnCompute" name="btnCompute">Compute Total</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code when replaced with mine will also show no total when compute total is clicked.

Comment: @J.Bush Now I reported the Whole your code, not simply the single function: run the snippet and tell me know.

Comment: Yes that snippet also works, only thing is, once you have one total your not able to click on something else and start over with a new total, I have figured out how to do it with the Code i started with! :)